# Wireless Internet Extremely slow on a TP-Link TL-WN821N

Tags: wireless

After I updated from 11.04 to 11.10 the internet barely works. Loading a webpage can take minutes and thats even if it works in the first place. I have now idea if this is a bug and if it is how am I supposed to update? The internet doesnt work and just crashes! Please help.

Wireless card: TP-Link TL-WN821N

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub [8086:2770] (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL PCI Express Root Port [8086:2771] (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GH (ICH7DH) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b0] (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller [8086:27df] (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller [8086:27c0] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc RV790 [Radeon HD 4890] [1002:9460]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: ATI Technologies Inc HD48x0 audio [1002:aa30]
02:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Agere Systems FW322/323 [11c1:5811] (rev 70)
02:05.0 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23418 Single-Chip MPEG-2 Encoder with Integrated Analog Video/Broadcast Audio Decoder [14f1:5b7a]
02:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family LAN Controller [8086:27dc] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the link I've posted so we can see more hardware information.

Comment: cross-reference [TP-LINK TL-WN821N automatically disconnects](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70271/tp-link-tl-wn821n-automatically-disconnects)

Comment: I presume ubuntu 11.04 used older version of wireless driver. Have you tried using that older version instead?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems on my Thinkpad X1. Disabling wireless N solved that. What wireless driver/kernel module are you using?

```
#/etc/modprobe.d/_wlan.conf 
options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

Comment: I'm on a desktop but using a wireless adapter TP-Link TL-WN821N

Comment: Unforchanitly this did not work

Comment: The file is "/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf" and the line to add is "options ath9k 11n_disable=1". It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, I'd suggest buying hardware that's fully supported in linux to not deal with these issues:  http://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/networking-modems

Second, you listed your PCI cards, while apparently you have a usb wifi card.

However, if you look here, someone seems to have gotten your card working in 11.10
http://myubuntunotes.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/hello-world/