# TP-LINK TL-WN821N automatically disconnects

Tags: wireless

I have a problem with my usb wireless stick (TP-LINK TL-WN821N) when I'm surfing on the net or something like that, so in every ~30 minutes I get disconnected from the internet, unfortunatly whent it happens I always have to unplug and then connect this usb device so that I can connect to the internet again.

ps: under windows it works properly and under the previous version of ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do the trick proposed in the comment 13 of this Launchpad bug, that is to blacklist the ar9170usb driver:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-backports-modules-2.6.32/+bug/495562

Comment: yes i did the same ..blacklist the driver and it worked properly

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a driver bug. See the official documentation for that card:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link

And the bug reports in launchpad:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/540827
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/549140

Some fixes / workarounds are described. Disabling the N-thingy seemed to work accoding to this answer:

- [Wireless Internet Extremely slow on a TP-Link TL-WN821N](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67638/wireless-internet-extremely-slow-on-a-tp-link-tl-wn821n/67640#67640)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i "solved" the problem by manually configuring wireless!
HOW TO:
1) Make a config file like this:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
        ssid="Your_neworkName"
        psk="Password"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=WPA2
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188) for more details how to. And save it to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf
2) Disable your network manager:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop
```

then test your configuration by running:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf
```

Is everything working? Nice go ahead to step 3)

3) Make a new script on your desktop called connect.sh containing

```
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop
ifconfig wlan0 down
dhclient -r wlan0
wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf
dhclient wlan0
```

and assure it is runnable.

4) Install "alacarte" (if Ubuntu 11.10) and create a new Launcher in Network Menu:

- Name: Connnect
- Command: gksudo /path/to/your/script.sh
- Description and icon: everything you like.

5)Search for "Connect" on your Dash and drag and drop it to your Dock ;)

6)Everytime you need to connect to your network just launch "Connect app" and it's done.

N.B. You need to configure every wireless network by hand!!!
Please contact me if something doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with my stick (TP-LINK TL-WN821N V3). After downloading latest network drivers by following this blog entry, it works a lot better:

http://whilesurfing.blogspot.com/2012/02/ubuntu-tp-link-tl821nv3-tl822n-v20.html

Answer (score 0):

The below link is an correct solution for TL-WN823N / WN821N Driver
https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Hello Abu, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way, in case your link goes down, the answer will still be available through Ask Ubuntu **;-)**.