# Internal WiFi adapter

Tags: wireless, 12.10

i'm new to ubuntu, i've tried some of the past versions, but i can say that 12.10 is my first...
I'm thinking about buying an internal WiFi adapter, but since the one i can use on Win XP and 7 doesn't work properly on Ubuntu, i wanted to ask if someone had any advice. I'm already pointed to something like TP-LINK 
TL-WN881ND
TL-WN781ND
TL-WN851ND
But, seing my prevous experiences I would like to know if someone has already tested one of them...

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: what problem you are facing with the existing? most wireless issues are fixed by installing additional drivers and some tweaks.

Comment: i looked a lot on the web but didn't find anything... anyway, I'm using a TP-LINK TL-WN821N which really often gets stuck, i mean, the wifi indicator in the status bar says me that there is full radio segnal (is just 2 lines), and the light on the light on the usb stops blinking (it becomes or fix on or fix off). Then Chromium (and Firefox) stops responding, Transmission opens up but doesnt connect. The Ping command to google from the terminal says that the host is unknown.

Comment: In a few words, it disconnects, so i have to unplug the USB pen, and when i see that the computer is disconnected, i plug it in again and it immediately works. I tried a lot of things found on this and other forums, but nothing helped. note: This adapter works with the ath9k_htc driver    thanks

Comment: give a try here - http://askubuntu.com/q/70271/35775, also look this [search](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=TP-LINK+TL-WN821N+)

Comment: Didn't work at all :( Does anyone have the answer to the question i asked?

Answer (score 2):

The TL-WN781ND is supported by Ubuntu according to  http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2012-11-01-tp-link-tl-wn781nd-pcie-150mbps. If you are searching WiFi cards with good Linux supported The Linux-Hardware-Guide (especially http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/category/network/wireless) should be a good spot to start.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.