# How to connect to tp-link wn881nd pci card wifi in Ubuntu 16.04 lts?

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros, tp-link

I'm stating in Ubuntu and I couldn't config my pci wifi card. It is seeing my network, but, when I call to connect it runs for fews seconds trying to connect and call again for the password (the password is writted right...).

My device is a Tp-link Wn881wd Atheros AR9287.

When I look at terminal "lspci" it returns the informations about the hardware.

I follow the @Otacon answer [Example @otacon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70271/tp-link-tl-wn821n-automatically-disconnects) but at the step of run the "wpa_supplicant" it show this message bellow. Any tip?

```
#my terminal response to "wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf"
```

> root@isaque-desktop:/home/isaque# wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf
>
> Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
>
> Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
>
> WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
>
> wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 16.04 the default wlan0 device does not exist, instead there is some fancy name like  wlp2s0.
Use this command to determine your wlan interface name:

```
ifconfig
```

After that correct your wpa supplicant init command:

```
wpa_supplicant -D wext -i  wlp2s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf
```

Remember, the  wlp2s0 interface name comes from your ifconfig command, change it accordingly.

Comment: Hi @kukulo, I try your suggestion, but no success. I used 
      ifconfig
And it returns:
enp0s20f0u12 Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW ......

enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 70:.......

lo        Link encap:Loopback Local  
          inet end.: ........
So I try  use "-i lo", next I try "-i enp0s31f6", and after "-i enp0s31f6", no success....
Any other tip?

Comment: I try to run a code to "sudo wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info" and in some part there is no "wirelless extensions", look:

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u12  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: wlp2s0 is your interface name.

Comment: Hi @kukulo, I try but it returns some kind of "busy" status, take a look:
a# first part:

root@isaque-desktop:/home/isaque# wpa_supplicant -D wext -i  wlp2s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf    
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant  
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWSCAN]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-1 retry=1
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 5c:e3:0e:02:7b:fb (SSID='Homesweethome' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp2s0: Associated with 5c:e3:0e:02:7b:fb
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=5c:e3:0e:02:7b:fb reason=0

Comment: #second part: 

wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=5c:e3:0e:02:7b:fb reason=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWSCAN]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-1 retry=1
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 5c:e3:0e:02:7b:fb (SSID='Homesweethome' freq=2437 MHz)

And repeats......

Comment: I try to connect in the network, and all the same: open the connections window -> put the password -> it run 3 or 4 seconds -> and re-open the password window, and keep repeating....

Comment: Edit your wpa.conf file and supply the network and credentials

Comment: I try to change the "wpa.conf", but is in a folder "/run/user/1000/gvfs" with permission denied, included as a "su root password". Any other suggestion.

Comment: The strange part is, I connect using my mobile and usb cable, and it works fine. No configurations needed. But the pci express card have been very complicaded.

Comment: with sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf you can change your wpa.conf.

Comment: I create a " /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa.conf " using sudo gedit with my SSID and Password, but not working until now...

Comment: @IsaqueDaniel you have created `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa.conf` but this is the wrong file - there should be an existing file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_conf.conf` (note the filename is `wpa_conf.conf` and not `wpa.conf`). You can find syntax examples online to make sure you are putting the info correctly. Also instead of `ifconfig` to list adapters, you can use `iwconfig` on the command line to list wifi adpters only - anything starting with `enp0*` as per your examples above is an ethernet adapter and not relevant to this discussion.