# How can I get in contact with an Ubuntu developer to help with a problem?

Tags: community

I have an Ubuntu problem and after posting it on here I got no answers. I need this problem fixed and I would like to get in email or Twitter contact with an Ubuntu expert.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may get support through [Ubuntu's official support](http://www.ubuntu.com/support) but I am absolutely convinced that if you ask properly and be patient, you will get answers to your problems.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem ( [Wireless Internet Extremely slow on a TP-Link TL-WN821N](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67638/wireless-internet-extremely-slow-on-a-tp-link-tl-wn821n) ) isn't really an "ubuntu problem" but a hardware problem; your wifi card seems to be poorly supported as the wifi manufacturer does not release linux drivers for their card.

An ubuntu developer wouldn't be able to really help you.

In the future, I'd recommend buying hardware that's known to be fully supported in linux; e.g., buying a desktop from system76, zareason, thinkpenguin, or ovaha.  Or [certified hardware](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport) e.g., [a linux supported wifi card](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)   Most drivers for wireless cards have to be written by someone for each specific chipset which takes some time (and maybe trial and error to figure out what the windows drivers are doing), so if its a relatively new card that no one's taken the time to get all the features working (e.g., 802.11n internet) it may not work perfectly.  May I suggest just running a CAT5 ethernet cable in the meantime?

Comment: Looks like a good answer, but I think it'd be better located at the other question rather than here.

Comment: So I'm going to have to wait for someone to get the Linux driver for 11.10 working before I can use it?

Comment: @WarringIng64 - I somewhat agree; but I chose here as this is where he described it as a "ubuntu problem" needing an "ubuntu developer".

Comment: @ bmazoka - An ubuntu developer wouldn't be able to help you as they likely don't have a random wifi card by manufacturers that don't care to support linux.  But users have gotten your card to work as a simple google search shows  http://myubuntunotes.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/hello-world/

Answer (score 6):

Some of the Ubuntu Developers also offer their help here in Askubuntu. Even if it takes a litte more time (Most of the time you will get an answer before the end of the day).

And not just Developers but also Ubuntu users in all levels of knowledge. From experts and beginners to Developers and programmers.